# Django + nginx redirect loop for home /

Tags: python, django, nginx

I've a really strange problem. It's not the first page i've published in this way but the first with this behavior.

My site is configured to redirect: http://marclab.de to http://marclab.de/

*BUT*

it redirects also http://marclab.de/ to http://marclab.de/?

the browser seems to compensate this misconfiguration, but google not.

I've 2 curl calls:

```
~ $ curl -v http://marclab.de
* Rebuilt URL to: http://marclab.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 78.138.113.215...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fe1cb80a200
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fe1cb80a200) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to marclab.de (78.138.113.215) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.34.0
> Host: marclab.de
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 09:29:44 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4
< Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: http://marclab.de/
< Content-Language: en
< Set-Cookie: django_language=en; expires=time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=11, tm_min=34, tm_sec=47, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=178, tm_isdst=0); Max-Age=31536000; Path=/
< 
* Connection #0 to host marclab.de left intact
```

and with trailing slash: (which looks almost the same)

```
~ $ curl -v http://marclab.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 78.138.113.215...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fa65b008200
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fa65b008200) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to marclab.de (78.138.113.215) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.34.0
> Host: marclab.de
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 09:32:47 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
* Server WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4 is not blacklisted
< Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4
< Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: http://marclab.de/
< Content-Language: en
< Set-Cookie: django_language=en; expires=time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=27, tm_hour=11, tm_min=37, tm_sec=50, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=178, tm_isdst=0); Max-Age=31536000; Path=/
< 
* Connection #0 to host marclab.de left intact
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  marclab.de;

      root         /dev/null;

      try_files  $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri;

      location / {
        client_max_body_size 5M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_pass        http://app01:3001/;
      }
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the Problem. I'm using django-cms with multiple language support. There was no content for the default language set up.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you meant nginx config, not curl, right?
Any way, it seems you implement redirection with your python application. I can't give you any advise in that case. But I can advise you to delegate this job to nginx. Something like this:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  marclab.de;

  root         /dev/null;

  try_files  $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri;

  location ~ ^/(.+)[^/]?/$ {
    rewrite ^/(.+)[^/]?/$ $1/ permanent;
  }

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass        http://app01:3001/;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
}
```

please, try it in testing environment before using on public. I wrote it by my memory and didn't test it.